# Kafka how to know the latest created partition id for a topic in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am creating partition for a topic dynamically using AdminUtils. I have to get the partitionId of the newly created partition for saving it in Mysql for my business logic. How can I achieve this ? 
My current code :

```
 AdminUtils.addPartitions(zkUtils,KAFKA_PRODUCER_TOPIC,currentPartitionCount+1,"",true);

            List<PartitionInfo> infoList = producer.partitionsFor(KAFKA_PRODUCER_TOPIC);
            for(PartitionInfo info : infoList){
                System.out.println(info.partition());
            }
            createdPartionId = infoList.get(0).partition();
```

Problem with above is that latest created partition is not coming in the PartitionInfo list. Don't know why.producer is the Kafka Producer API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `TopicMetadataRequest`. See [**the example**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Finding+Topic+and+Partition+Leader). You can do one before and after and compare the results. Otherwise, the new partition always gets added with a `newPartitionID == previousLastPartitionID + 1`